# GCloud Dataflow recreate BigQuery table if it gets deleted during job run

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have set up a GCloud Dataflow pipeline which consumes messages from a Pub/Sub subscription, converts them to table rows and writes those rows to a corresponding BigQuery table.

Table destination is decided based on the contents of the Pub/Sub message and will occasionally lead to the situation that a table does not exist yet and has to be created first. For this I use create disposition `CREATE_IF_NEEDED`, which works great.

However, I have noticed that if I manually delete a newly created table in BigQuery while the Dataflow job is still running, Dataflow will get stuck and will not recreate the table. Instead I get an error:

```
Operation ongoing in step write-rows-to-bigquery/StreamingInserts/StreamingWriteTables/StreamingWrite for at least 05m00s without outputting or completing in state finish at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method) at
    java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175) at
    java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.awaitDone(FutureTask.java:429) at
    java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191) at
    org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryServicesImpl$DatasetServiceImpl.insertAll(BigQueryServicesImpl.java:816) at
    org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryServicesImpl$DatasetServiceImpl.insertAll(BigQueryServicesImpl.java:881) at
    org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.StreamingWriteFn.flushRows(StreamingWriteFn.java:143) at
    org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.StreamingWriteFn.finishBundle(StreamingWriteFn.java:115) at
    org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.StreamingWriteFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeFinishBundle(Unknown Source)
```

If I go back to BigQuery and manually recreate this table, Dataflow job will continue working.

However, I am wondering if there is a way to instruct the Dataflow pipeline to **recreate the table if it gets deleted during the job run**?

[image: GCloud Dataflow pipeline]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in the current `BigqueryIO` connector. From the github link of the connector present [here](https://github.com/kl0u/beam/blob/master/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io/BigQueryIO.java#L1060) you will observe that for `StreamingWriteFn` which is what your code, the table creation process is done in `getOrCreateTable` and this is called in `finishBundle`. There is a map of `createdTables` that is maintained and in `finishBundle` the table gets created if it not is already present, once it is present and stored in the hashmap it is not re-created as shown below:-

```
    public TableReference getOrCreateTable(BigQueryOptions options, String tableSpec)
        throws IOException {
      TableReference tableReference = parseTableSpec(tableSpec);
      if (!createdTables.contains(tableSpec)) {
        synchronized (createdTables) {
          // Another thread may have succeeded in creating the table in the meanwhile, so
          // check again. This check isn't needed for correctness, but we add it to prevent
          // every thread from attempting a create and overwhelming our BigQuery quota.
          if (!createdTables.contains(tableSpec)) {
            TableSchema tableSchema = JSON_FACTORY.fromString(jsonTableSchema, TableSchema.class);
            Bigquery client = Transport.newBigQueryClient(options).build();
            BigQueryTableInserter inserter = new BigQueryTableInserter(client);
            inserter.getOrCreateTable(tableReference, WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
                CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED, tableSchema);
            createdTables.add(tableSpec);
          }
        }
      }
      return tableReference;
    }
```

For you to meet your requirement you might have to maintain your own BigqueryIO wherein you don't perform this specific check

```
if (!createdTables.contains(tableSpec)) {
```

The more important question though is why would the table get deleted in a production system by itself? This problem should be fixed rather than trying to re-create the table from Dataflow.

Comment: It won't get deleted in the production environment. My question was out of curiosity to know whether it is possible to set it up in such a way or not. Thanks for looking into code.